# JIRA Automation: ReadOnly in UI, Update via REST API

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

How can we create a custom field which is not editable in the JIRA UI, but we can update using via the JIRA REST API?

Automation can update the field using PUT and json body, but the problem is that our users are editing the field in the JIRA user interface, which corrupts the information written by the tooling.  We'd like it to be visible but not editable.

We found the following post which explains the issue, but found that the technique did not work.
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-have-a-Jira-custom-field-read-only-in-the-interface-but/qaq-p/358254